# Improve Panorama view performance in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I have a panorama page as my mainpage, there was only 3 pages, however for some reasons the slide doesn't go smoothly as usual (In my emulator it's smooth but when I build it into my LG optimus 7, there is a noticeable lag when sliding page to page)
I have place a fancy big image as panorama backgrounds (about 1024*800 and 175KB ), I also have a mask for each panoramaitems. Is this the cause of problem? Because I didn't implement any code yet, just a pure design and simple mediaplayer control.
I also use MemoryDiagnosticsHelper to check memory usage and it's about 35mb to 40mb.
Where could be the problem and how to improve the performance?

Answer (score 2):

If  by mask you mean OpacityMask then that's likely to be the issue. That's because OpacityMask forces rendering of the panorama on the UI thread, not the Composition thread.

Performance testing does all need to happen on a real device as it has very different (slower) hardware to your average PC.